# Why does my path for python 3.8 have python 3.9 in it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, homebrew

Every time I try to run `% brew list python` it returns `Error: No such keg: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9`. I think this is because I used python 3.9 up until recently - I uninstalled it and instead installed python 3.8 using homebrew. I removed all references of python 3.9 from `/usr/local/bin`, but still get that error when I run `brew list python`. Running `% env` returns this path: `PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin` which doesn't make any sense. Why does python 3.8 have references to python 3.9? I think this is the cause of my `brew list python` issue. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When you first installed 3.9, homebrew added the 3.9 directory to your `PATH` environment variable in one of your shell startup files.

Installing 3.8 didn't remove this, it just added the 3.8 directories ahead of it.

Look for this in your startup scripts (the specific script depends on your shell, it could be `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, `.profile`, or something similar) and remove the 3.9 directories that you don't need any more.

Or just ignore it, since the 3.8 directory is first, so it will take precedence.

Comment: I can't find any of the scripts you mentioned, I tried using `cd ~/.bashrc` and `cd ~/.profile`, but it says those don't exist.

Comment: Why are you trying to `cd` to them? They're not directories.